# Android accessibilty bold text not working in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, accessibility

I am building a flutter app. In the app the text font weight wants to bold if android accessibility settings bold text enabled. In my code when using `MediaQueryData` and `useInheritedMediaQuery. But it will bold when if disabled  android accessibility settings. How to fix this issue.

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window).copyWith(boldText: true),
          child:MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
          ));
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;

    @override
    State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Text Wants to be bold',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```